# Zip/UnZip File on Webserver using our iphone

Tags: iphone, zip, webserver

> Is it Possible to Zip/UnZip  File on Webserver using our iphone to use that file ?

If it is, please guide me how can I do that?

My Problem is I want to upload/Download a  **Folder**  from  **webserver to local**    and I do that by first zip local folder and then upload it from webserver..

**Is it right way to Upload/Download folder by Creating Zip?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Its Over.
Using RecursionFunction this will Complete... No need to Zip/Unzip folder..      
     -(void)recursiveMethod:(NSString *)strPath
{

```
[client1 initWithHost:@"HostName" username:self.username password:self.password];
NSArray *listFiles = [[NSArray alloc]init];


//Fetching data from document directory.
//    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    
//    // Get documents folder
//    NSString *docDir  = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:strPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir)
{
    subpaths = [fm subpathsAtPath:strPath];
}
listFiles = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:strPath error:nil];
NSLog(@"listFiles ==== %@",listFiles);

for(int j=0; j < [listFiles count] ;j++)
{
//Check For Folder

if([[listFiles objectAtIndex:j]rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)
    {

    self.folderName = [self.folderName stringByAppendingPathComponent:[listFiles    objectAtIndex:j]];

 //Create Current Folder 
[client1 createCollection:self.folderName];
 self.countItemsInFolder = 0; //countItemsInFolder is int(counter) 

//call recursiveMethod again
strPath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[listFiles objectAtIndex:j]];
        [self recursiveMethod:strPath];
        self.folderName = [self.folderName stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        strPath = [strPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    }
    else
    {
        //upload Files
        self.countItemsInFolder = j+1;
        [self appdelegate].remoteFolderForUpload = self.folderName;
        NSString *destiFilePath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[listFiles objectAtIndex:j]];
        [client1 uploadFile:[listFiles objectAtIndex:j] toPath:self.folderName fromPath:destiFilePath];
    }

}

if([listFiles count] == self.countItemsInFolder)
{
    strPath = [strPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

-(void)updateFromInternet

{

progressView.progress = 0;

```
//save to a temp file
NSString* updateURL = @"http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/LargeAppUpdate.zip";
NSLog(@"Checking update at : %@", updateURL);

progressView.hidden = NO;
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSURLRequest* updateRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:updateURL]];
NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:updateRequest delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

NSLog(@"Download start...");

}

if u have any query check this link

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/update-dynamically-your-iphone-app-with-new-content/

Answer (score 0):

Download
 - download zip from server and unzip it.

Upload
 - Zip the files on device using [miniZip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html)  and upload to server

- Unzip the .zip on server. Use a script to do this automatically. Not necessarily to remote control the unzip process on server through iPhone.